# How to get list of shapes in SdtBlock element using Open XML SDK?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, word-2010

How can I get the list of shapes (textboxs) in an SdtBlock element using Open XML SDK?

Regards.

Comment: Or how can I get the list of shapes in a wordDocumentProcessing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to grab all the shapes in a `WordProcessingDocument` you can use linq to traverse all the descendants of the body:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
{
    IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape> shapes = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape>();
}
```