# Get Shapes From A Word Doc Programmatically

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get shapes from a word Document either using OpenXML or Interop Word? Any links/answers are appreciated

Comment: You can refer to similar question asked in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805882/how-to-get-list-of-shapes-in-sdtblock-element-using-open-xml-sdk

Comment: Thanks *thumbs up*